# Windows - GDI - Scaling a screen DC to a printer DC without modifying the draw functions

Tags: windows, printing, scale, viewport, gdi

I'm writing a Windows application showing a document to the user. The content is painted using the GDI functions, and all appears as expected on the screen.

Now I want to print this document. I get a printer device context, and I do the exact same drawing as I do on the screen. Of course the printed content appears tiny on the top of the printed page. The reason of this behavior is clear for me, and is fully explained here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/764057/GDI-Drawing-and-Printing

So I need to add a scaled viewport on my printer DC, and there are several functions to achieve that in the GDI. However I'm a little puzzled about HOW to configure these functions. I tried various examples found on the internet, but none of them worked for me.

My screen resolution is 1920x1080 pixels, and I'm trying to print on an A4 portrait page. I tested various configurations, and I found that the best approximation to fit on my printed page is the following:

```cpp
::SetMapMode(hDC, MM_ISOTROPIC);
::SetWindowExtEx(hDC, 1, 1, NULL);
::SetViewportExtEx(hDC, 5, 5, NULL);
::SetViewportOrgEx(hDC, -10200, 0, NULL);
```

As the screen and print configurations may, of course, change on other PC, I need to know how the above values may be calculated, but I cannot find a formula that works in my case. Especially I don't know why I need to scale my canvas origin using the SetViewportOrgEx() function, nobody mentioned that on the documents I read.

So what is the correct manner to calculate my print DC viewport, considering that:

- The exactly same painting functions will be used for both the screen and printer drawing, and I will NEVER write different functions to print on the screen and the printer
- The screen and printer devices may be entirely configured by the user, but the printed result should always fit the document on both the screen and the printer

And as an additional question, it would be better to use a metafile to do this kind of job?

Comment: A universal method would be to use SetWorldTransform, using an own function delivering the XFORM calculatet from input parameters e.g. xoffs, xoffs, scale, rotation for intuitive handling.

Comment: It's a possibility. However the MSDN documentation says that the graphic mode must be set to GM_ADVANCED to achieve that. Is this mode commonly compatible with all the printer contexts?

Comment: It is not supported by all printers, I don't know how common it is (and did not find information about). Never having had problems on my own should not be a reason for you, since the target environment might differ..

Comment: In fact, this solution cannot be used in my case anyway, because GDI+ is also used in a part of my draw and this solution seems to provide different results with GDI and GDI+. I don't know if it's a misusage of my part of of GDI+, but the issues I face with this method does not appear with the above mentioned viewport. So I will continue to search in this direction. But thank you for the idea.

Comment: I don't know where you got those values, 1, 5, -10200. I tried it with XPS printer it didn't work. GDI+ still uses `HDC`, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: In fact it was an hardcoded estimation, because while I tested these functions to understand how they worked, I noticed that my drawing tended to going out of my page (the drawing was centered on my page width). I strongly suspected it was due to a mistake, and in fact I noticed recently that I not used the correct size to do my drawing calculation, as I used the printer page size instead of the source client size. This mistake distorted my calculation, and forced me to introduce an arbitrary compensation, which is this strange value above. To understand this was a step closer to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to map the screen coordinates to paper coordinates, we need the width and length of the paper. This information is available in `GetDeviceCaps(hdc, PHYSICALWIDTH)` and `GetDeviceCaps(hdc, PHYSICALHEIGHT)`, where `hdc` is printer's device context. We already have the screen coordinates somewhere.

The printer cannot print on the edges of the paper. We can get that information from `PHYSICALOFFSETX` and `PHYSICALOFFSETY`.

The example below uses uses a common function `paint` which does all the painting. `print` doesn't do any painting, it calls `paint` instead.

This assumes that `rc.left` and `rc.right` is `(0,0)` in screen coordinates.

```
void paint(HDC hdc, RECT rc)
{
    HBRUSH brush = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOWTEXT);
    InflateRect(&rc, -10, -10);
    FrameRect(hdc, &rc, brush);
    DrawText(hdc, L"hello world", -1, &rc, 0);
}

void print(HWND hWnd, RECT rc)
{
    PRINTDLG pd = { sizeof(pd) };
    pd.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    pd.Flags = PD_RETURNDC;
    if(!PrintDlg(&pd))
        return;

    HDC hdc = pd.hDC;
    DOCINFO doc = { sizeof(doc) };
    StartDoc(hdc, &doc);
    StartPage(hdc);
    SetMapMode(hdc, MM_ISOTROPIC);
    SetWindowExtEx(hdc, rc.right, rc.bottom, NULL);
    SetViewportExtEx(hdc, 
      GetDeviceCaps(hdc, PHYSICALWIDTH), GetDeviceCaps(hdc, PHYSICALHEIGHT), NULL);
    SetViewportOrgEx(hdc,
      -GetDeviceCaps(hdc, PHYSICALOFFSETX), -GetDeviceCaps(hdc, PHYSICALOFFSETY), NULL);

    paint(hdc, rc);

    EndPage(hdc);
    EndDoc(hdc);
    DeleteObject(hdc);
}
```

Testing:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
    paint(hdc, rc);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    break;
}

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
{
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
    print(hwnd, rc);
    break;
}
```

Comment: I now understood my mistake. First I used the incorrect size to calculate my drawing, second I also used clipping in my draw. Apparently the GDI clipping functions does not work well with the viewport functions and/or the printer DC. But at least removing them and applying the above solution achieved a final drawing highly closer to the final result I expected. Thank you for the answer.